# What is the Difference between T(n) (reccurence relations), Big O and Big Theta

Tags: algorithm, analysis, recurrence, big-o

I am wondering about this for my Algorithm class. It seems to be unclear what the difference is between BigO, Big Theta, and Recurrence relations (T(n))
For example: T(n) = 4T(n/3) + O(1)

Comment: More suited for cs.stackexchange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *recurrence relation* is a way of recursively defining a function. For example, the recurrence relation

> T(n) = 4T(n / 3) + O(1)

says that the function is defined so that if you want to determine T(n), you can evaluate T(n / 3), multiply it by 4, an add in some term that's O(1). You can think of the recurrence relation as a way of describing how a function is defined without actually coming up with an explicit formula for it.

Once you have a recurrence relation, though, you'll usually want to figure out some way to get a sense for what kind of function it describes. Does it describe a linear function? Something quadratic? Something exponential?

*Big-O notation* and *Big-Θ notation* are tools for describing the long-term growth rates of functions and for categorizing functions into different groups by their growth rates. Big-O notation is used to give upper bounds on a function, while big-Θ notation is used to give both upper and lower bounds on a function.

For example, using the Master Theorem, we can claim that the recurrence you have above is such that T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>3</sub> 4</sup>). By this, we mean that the function that's implicitly described by T(n) grows approximately at the rate of the function n<sup>log<sub>3</sub> 4</sup>. We can formalize this by introducing a formal definition of big-O notation.

When we say that T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>3</sub> 4</sup>), though, we're not precluding the possibility that T(n) is actually a much smaller function, though. For example, if T(n) = 5, it's true that T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>3</sub> 4</sup>), though it doesn't say much. If we make the stronger claim that T(n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>3</sub> 4</sup>), we're asserting that, in the long term, T(n) grows at the same rate as n<sup>log<sub>3</sub> 4</sup>.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! This tied everything together for me!